# Can't connect to MySQL database in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have a WCF Project in Visual Studio 2010. I have a MySQL database to which I want to connect. I installed MySQL Connector 6.6.5.
I click Server Explorer -> Add Connection, choose MySQL Data Provider, enter the host name, the username, password, but it doesn't connect to the database, and shows a message (when I click "Test Connection"):

> "Authentication to host ** for user ** using method
>   'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user
>   ***@IP_address (using password: YES)"

How can I solve this problem and connect to the database?

Comment: you can solve this by logging in with the credentials for a mysql user who is authorized to connect form your host

Comment: How can I do this? I have one user and I'm trying to log in with its username and password...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you had install phpmyadmin, you can check permission and credential information
please see my screenshot for detail info. I had to change my listening port to :90 cos I am also running IIS like you.You can get Xampp(to get phpmyadmin) from here. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

[image]